# connect MYSQL with netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

Iam new on using NetBeans 7.4 , i want to connect my java application to MYSQL , the application is desktop application .
i have already install MYSQL workbench 5.2 and create database with one table .
from NetBeans services on Databases i register MYSQL server , i enter these values :
localhost : 127.0.0.1 , user : root and password : root.

[image: from NetBeans]

NetBeans ask me to set MYSQL command Path (Path to start command) i insert this path :
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 5.1\myodbc-installer.exe

from main class in java i saw from net how to set connection :

```
 Connection conn = null;
    try {
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sameer", "root","root");
  System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

but all time the exception will execute :

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sameer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the mysql connector jar in your project.

If you haven't downloaded it yet you can find it here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Once you have downloaded it:

- right click on the project
- select Properties
- select Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder
- navigate your file system to select the jar you previously downloaded
- save and it will run correctly